# Nvidia error - Resolution changes abruptly

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

Since a couple of weeks, resolution of my screen changes regularly from 2048x1152 to 1048x768.  I have tried various settings and manipulations related to NVIDIA (including changing the drivers) but, so far nothing completely solves the problem.
The symptoms are:

- Resolution often changes (NOT always) when I open the `System Parameters` application or when I open the display part of this application. That switch can happen from low-res to hi-res or the opposite.  This way, I can sometimes get the system to work in hi-res.
- When I log in, I regularly get the message (sometimes in hi-res, mostly in low-res):

> ```
> none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
> Trying modes for CRTC 586
> CRTC 586: trying mode 1024x768@60Hz with output at 2048x1152@60Hz (pass 0)
> CRTC 586: trying mode 1360x768@60Hz with output at 2048x1152@60Hz (pass 0)
> ...
> ```

- This seems to happen more often after hibenation.
- I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA drivers 340.98 (so far, using the proposed drivers 304.132 and X.Org did not change), on a card GT216 GeForce GT220.
- The above mentionned symptoms change with releases of Ununtu kernel.

Does anybody know if I can do something about this phenomen or just have to wait for a correct version of software (which one?)